# Code Treats .txt File Differently When Saved

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I have an input .txt file that looks something like this.

```
command1 param1
command2       param2
command3       param3
command4 param4
```

I am trying to reduce the extra whitespace so I implemented the code below to remove that.

```
string[] output = File.ReadAllText(InputFilePath).Split('\n').Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ")).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(OutputFilePath, output);
```

If I run the code on the file without doing anything, the code does not work.

However, If I manually go into the input file and just save it without changing anything and then run the code again, it works fine.

I believe this is some sort of UTF-16/8 issue but I am not sure how to account for it. What can I do?

Comment: Instead of reading the whole file and splitting it by `\n`, you should use `File.ReadAllLines(InputFilePath)`. Then you at least avoid errors caused by different line breaks (`\n`, `\r\n`, `\r`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out although that doesn't fix the issue described.

Comment: Maybe you got different whitespace chars within the source file. You could try using `\p{Z}+` as pattern. That matches any kind of whitespace or invisible separator chars.

Comment: \p{Z} didn't work but thanks for pointing me down the right path, tried \p{C}+ and it worked, which is "invisible control characters and unused code points"

Comment: @NiuqNavig Since you found a solution to your problem, please consider posting and accepting an answer to your question. Accepted answers are much more helpful to the community than solutions posted as comments. Be sure to post the working code as part of your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case there were "invisible control characters and unused code points". Using regular expressions to remove those characters resolved the issue.

```
string[] output = File.ReadAllLines(InputFilePath).Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"\p{C}+", "")).ToArray();
```